# How to stop firefox from opening "Content-Disposition: attachment"

Tags: http, selenium-webdriver, firefox, browser, download

How can I prevent Firefox from automatically opening an XML file with a "Content-Disposition: attachment" header, I only want to download it.

Comment: Did you see the compatibility notes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#compatibility_notes ?